# Curl POST in python or similar method

Tags: python, curl, post, urllib2

This might be a little too much direct question. New to Python

I am trying to Parse/Scrape video link from a video website(Putlocker).
Ie    http://www.putlocker.com/file/A189D40E3E612C50.

The page comes up initially with this code below or similar

```
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="3d0865fbb040e670" name="hash">
<input name="confirm" type="submit" value="Continue as Free User" 
disabled="disabled"  
 id="submitButton" class="confirm_button" style="width:190px;">
</form>
```

value="3d0865fbb040e670" Changes everytime...

```
Import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.putlocker.com/file/A189D40E3E612C50.'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
page = response.read()
```

from here i find the Value="?" of Hash

then

```
url = 'http://www.putlocker.com/file/A189D40E3E612C50.'
values = {'hash' : 3d0865fbb040e670}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
page = response.read()
```

But I end up on same page again. Do I post value="Continue as Free User" as well?
How do I go ahead with posting both data.

A working code would be helpful.
I am trying hard but no avail yet.

Ok..after the suggestion made by few programmers

I tried with codes like below

```
url = 'http://www.putlocker.com/file/A189D40E3E612C50'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
r = re.search('value="([0-9a-f]+?)" name="hash"', html)
session_hash = r.group(1)
print session_hash
form_values = {} 
form_values['hash'] = session_hash
form_values['confirm'] = 'Continue as Free User'
data = urllib.urlencode(form_values)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, data=data) 
html = response.read()
print html
```

So I am returned with same page again again..What am I doing wrong here!! I have seen something called pycurl..but I want use something simpler..Any clue??

Comment: Just to clarify, you are successfully grabbing the value of the hidden hash and your question is just how to send an HTTP POST request instead of an HTTP GET, correct?

Comment: Yes just to post...Going to check the suggestions by others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urllib2.urlopen(url,data=data)`

Answer (score 1):

You do need to give your encoded `values` parameter to the `urlopen` command:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, data)
```

otherwise you will create another GET request instead of POSTing.

Comment: Ok. I have tried with response = urllib2.urlopen(url, data)..same result..Same page returns..
There is another input <input name="confirm" type="submit" value="Continue as Free User" disabled="disabled"  
 id="submitButton" class="confirm_button" style="width:190px;"> ...How do I post this button and post the hash together?

Comment: See the `name` and `value` attributes on that button? Add those to your `values` dictionary: `{'hash': '3d0865fbb040e670', 'confirm': 'Continue as Free User'}`.

Comment: I have tried that too...Please check if my second try code up there is ok or not? What am I missing!!

Comment: @AbulHasnat: Your code looks fine; it's the website you are trying to fool into accepting your post that is the problem. Their script detection is preventing your from pulling this off.